# Are there any free webhosts who offer SMTP to an email on a separate domain?

Tags: web-hosting, email, gmail

I have written up a PHP script that sends form inputs to an email. However, the free webhost that I've tried could only send SMTP to a domain that you owned. I don't have one yet, and can only use subdomains, and can't send to emails like gmail.com

Do you know of any free webhosts that let you send to gmail? It's just to test the script and see whether it works, and therefore it doesn't matter if there are ads or other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just testing the script, you could simply set up a PHP environment on your own computer using [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/) (Windows) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/) (Mac), then use your ISP's SMTP details or a Gmail account to send the email.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use WAMP with [Mercury Mail](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm). It allows you to easily set up a SMTP server on your computer.